# AlignArrayOfStructures Left formats struct incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

In a project where we have other complicated arrays of structures where AlignArrayOfStructures is needed we found this strange behavior of clang-format for a initializer of a struct in a union.

The problem seems to some amount be triggered by the comments last on the lines adding and removing comments changes the behavior.

.clang-format

```
{
    BasedOnStyle: LLVM,
    AlignArrayOfStructures: Left,
    IndentWidth:     4,
    ColumnLimit: 0,
}
```

Formatted output

```
const some_type_t someVar = {
    .something = {
                  SOME_ENUM,
                  sizeof(some_32_array) / sizeof(int32_t), // Size
        some_32_array, // Pointer to data
        44100                                    // Some comment
    }
};
```

Expected output

```
const some_type_t someVar = {
    .something = {
        SOME_ENUM,
        sizeof(some_32_array) / sizeof(int32_t), // Size
        some_32_array,                           // Pointer to data
        44100                                    // Some comment
    }
};
```

Any one have any suggestions for settings to modify to at least get the same alignment of the lines in the struct?